# If hasClass condition not working after Updating Class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is jQuery condition if hasclass not working when i update class from Jquery, What is reason ? Means if i change / Update class then also **Jquery if condition** working on click, Rather it should not work after that.

in my case, first of all the div `Some Content` has class `.L2D1` that's color is blue okay, then my jQuery condition is if `Some Content` has class `.L2D1` means till its color is blue then it should should change the color of `Some Other Content` div that's red.

But when i changed the class `.L2D1` from jQuery Onclick change class button, then it's class changed into `.newClass` then also my jQuery if condition working Why?

Where i am making mistake, plz make it solve. literally I don't able to get actual problem.

See this:

```js
$('.ChangeClass').click(function () {
$(".L2D1").attr('class', 'newClass');
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#L2D1-id").hasClass("L2D1")) {
    $('.ChangeColor').click(function () {
        $(".Layout-2").addClass('intro');
    });     
} 
});
```

```css
.intro {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}

.newClass {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: green;
}

.L2D1 {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="L2D1" id="L2D1-id"> Some Content </div>


<div class="Layout-2"> Some Other Content </div>

<button class="ChangeClass">Change Class</button>
<button class="ChangeColor"> <!-- if ($("#L2D1-id").hasClass("L2D1")) Then { -->  Change Color</button>
```

Comment: The `if` block only runs once; when the page loads.

Comment: then what is the solutio for that, like my situation.

Comment: Move the `if` block within the event handler, like Mohamed-Yousef's original comment recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event is created when your script is loaded. So the `if` statement is never tested after

To solve it you can put the `if` statement into your event, like :

```js
$('.ChangeClass').click(function() {
  $(".L2D1").attr('class', 'newClass');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.ChangeColor').click(function() {
    if ($("#L2D1-id").hasClass("L2D1")) {
      $(".Layout-2").addClass('intro');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.intro {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}

.newClass {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: green;
}

.L2D1 {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="L2D1" id="L2D1-id"> Some Content </div>


<div class="Layout-2"> Some Other Content </div>

<button class="ChangeClass">Change Class</button>
<button class="ChangeColor"> <!-- if ($("#L2D1-id").hasClass("L2D1")) Then { -->  Change Color</button>
```